# jQuery click event is not handled by my javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4.0 to build my web application and jQuery Dialog plugin for the popup. I intend to put my HTML elements in the div element with id 'addDialog' onto a popup. The popup should be shown on a button click with id 'add' but it's not working. Whenever I click the button nothing happens.

This is my View:

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "TimeSlotDetails";
}
<head>
  <title>TimeSlot</title>

  <link href="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Common.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobstrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/TimeSlotDetails.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div id="addDialog" style="display:none">

      Name<input type="text"/><br/><br/>
      Duration<input type="text"/><br/><br/>
      Type<input type="text"/><br/><br/>
      Frequency<input type="text"/><br/><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="title">Automatic Timetable Generator</div>
    <div class="title-down"></div>

    <table class="option_list">
      <tr>
        <td class="title-down" rowspan="16" colspan="3"></td>
        <td rowspan="16" colspan="5">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home")</div>
          <div>@Html.ActionLink("Preferred Time Slot", "PreferredTimeslot")</div>
          <div>Time Slot Details</div>
          <div>Department Details</div>
          <div>Subject Details</div>
          <div>ClassRoom Details</div>
          <div>Lab Details</div>
          <div>Allot the Slots for each classRoom as per your need</div>
          <div>Teacher Details</div>
          <div>Allot Subjects to Teachers</div>
          <div>Allot Subjects to Labs</div>
          <div>Check ot the Final Result</div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="16" colspan="12">

          <div>Enter the Time slot Details</div>
          <div>
            <span><input id="add" type="button" value="Add" /></span> <span><input id="edit" type="button" value="Edit" /></span> <span><input id="delete" type="button" value="Delete" /></span>
          </div>
          <table id="timeslotdetails">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Name</td>
                <td colspan="3">Duration</td>
                <td colspan="3">Type</td>
                <td colspan="3">Frequency</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div> <button id="slotAllottmentSubmit" type="Submit" value="Submit the Data">Submit the Data</button></div>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="16" colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#timeslotdetails').DataTable();

  $('.option-list #add').click(function () {
    $('#addDialog').css('display:inline');
    $('#addDialog').dialog();
  });
});
```

I have included all the dependent files in the right order.

Comment: `class="option_list"` vs `$('.option-list #add')` potential typo

Comment: okay. I'm accessing the button with id 'add' directly now but it's still not working.

Comment: I tried using the dialog plugin in another sample project just to test it out and it's working fine but it's not working on my main project

Comment: I really need to know the reason behind this problem.

Comment: I just got the solution of my problem. I just put my click event at the very start of document.ready function and it worked like a charm. But I still don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think the jQuery selector `$('.option-list #add')` is wrong.
I checked and I did not see any element having the `.option-list` class in the HTML.

You can try `$('#add')`.

Comment: I see, i used 'option-list' instead of 'option_list'. I am accessing the button directly without using the class of it's parent element but still it's not working.

Comment: Anything you can help me with this? I'm stuck in this problem for over a week now.